# Can Comparator compare two objects of different type?

Tags: java, comparator

I have two objects of classes Person and Employee.
Both classes  have common attribute age.
And I have added few objects of both theses classes to an Arraylist and now I want two write one Comparator and pass it to sort method of Collections class.
And want the list to be sorted on the basis of age.
I am trying this just for getting more clarity on use of Comparable and Comparator in Java.

EDIT:
Reason Why I was asking this question was that I was not clear about Comparator and Comparable.
I read somewhere that If Class implements Comparable then it can not be compared against objects of other classes (Because of Class cast exception).

Now if I create relation ship in Employee and Person then there is no need to implement Comparator (Unless I want to do sorting on the basis of name or other common attribute of these classes).

Once Again, I have asked this question to get more clarity on Comparator and Comparable.

Till now, What I have been able to understand is that If I want to do sorting on more than one parameters then I should implement Comparator and pass it to Collections.srot().

Or If I don't have control over the Class of object being sorted, then custom sorting I should implement Comparator.
(Correct me if I am wrong or I am missing something)

**EDIT**

I think now I understand the use of Comparable and Comparator.
To make sure I got the right concepts, here is what I understand:
If I want to compare two objects of different classes (and having no relation ) then I should use raw comparator and override the compare method.
Another reason why somebody would implement Comparator instead of Comparable is 
to have flexibility in sorting.
And what I understand from natural sorting is the logic implemented by Class in CompareTo method.

Hope I am correct with all these points.

Comment: Why don't you use interface (e.g. Ageable) make both Person and Employee implement it and compare two ageable objects?

Comment: @om-nom-nom That sounds like a great answer to this question.

Comment: If you don't use generics, sure.

Comment: I assume Employee extends Person,  no?

Comment: No, Employee does not extend person.

Comment: Why not? It would make sense to do so.

Comment: @oldrinb "If you don't use generics, sure." --How? I don't want to implement a common interface also? Thanks!!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  is there any other way apart from creating relationship in these two classes?

Comment: @AKS use a raw `Comparator` and implement `compare(Object, Object)`

Comment: @oldrinb but inside compare method i will have to make sure I cast Object to Person and Object To Employee. Because I am not sure how sort method of collection will pass first object as Person or Second object.. Am I right?

Comment: @oldrinb You can use a raw Comparator, but then you have to get the age property by reflection (or by down casting to an unknown type).

Comment: @AKS indeed... just use `instanceof`. Honestly, you should just implement a common interface as per om-nom-nom's advice.

Comment: @phlogratos you don't have to do either. `return (o1 instanceof Person ? ((Person) o1).age : ((Employee) o1).age) - (o2 instanceof Person ? ((Person) o2).age : ((Employee) o2).age);`

Comment: @oldrinb This is what I meant with down casting.

Comment: @phlogratos except the type isn't unknown.

Comment: yeah, use reflection and throw performance into window \*sarcasm\*

Comment: @oldrinb Before checking with instanceof it is unknown. You should also check that nobody calls the comparator with something different than Person or Employee, which is perfectly fine seen by the compiler.

Comment: @phlogratos everything is unknown prior to deduction... besides that, checking for both is pointless and not necessary given the set of constraints in the question.

Comment: Holding a collection of two very different types and trying to sort this *can* be done, but it's a very bad design,  and youd be creating a program that could break easily. I strongly advise you not to go this route.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I agree completely. But I wanted to make sure I understand use of Comparator/Comparable completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define an interface called Ageable and Employee and Person can implement this interface. Also you can define an abstract class (and Employee and Person will be inherited from the abstract class) with the same effect. Note that you can also use a normal class for this reason, you can do whatever you need.

Also, if there is no reason to say that an Employee is not a Person (for instance robots are working at the office) then Employee can be inherited from Person.

Answer (score 4):

I would make an Employee a sub-class of Person. (Assuming all your employees are people) Then you can create a `Comparator<Person>`

Comment: I'd better define an Ageable interface (as other users say). Subclassing could have unwanted side-effects

Comment: @polypiel Like treating an Employee as a Person when you don't mean to ;)

Answer (score 3):

You should create an interface `AgeProvider`:

```
public interface AgeProvider {
    int getAge();
}
```

Both `Person` and `Employee` should implement `AgeProvider`. Now you can implement a Comparator that compares 2 `AgeProvider`.