# Compare different object types with comparator

Tags: java, collections, compare

I need to write a Comparator that take an object A of type A and an object B of type B. The two object are not an extention of a common object. They are really diffferent, but I need to compare this two object by common fields in it. I have to use the comparator interface because the objects are stored in Set and after I have to do operations with CollectionUtils. I googled a little bit arround and I find solutions with Comparator but only with the same type.

I tried to implement a think in this direction but I don't know If I'm very on the correct way.

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<A>, Serializable {

  private B b;

  public MyComparator(B b){
       this.b = b;
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(A old, A otherOne) {
    int value = 0;
    if (!old.getField().equals(b.getField())) {
        value = 1;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

It's possible that an answer is always given, but I did not found the right words to search in Google. Have someone suggestions?

Txs

P.S: I add the two objects in diferent Set:

```
TreeSet<A> setA = new TreeSet<A>(myComparator);
TreeSet<B> setB = new TreeSet<B>(myComparator);
```

and after I would do thinks like this:

```
TreeSet<??????> retain = CollectionUtils.retainAll(setA, setB);
TreeSet<??????> remove = CollectionUtils.removeAll(setA, setB);
```

Comment: A similar question is asked here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414288/can-comparator-compare-two-objects-of-different-type

Comment: How would you expect to *use* this comparator? Everything I can think of that has a comparator parameter is dealing with a single type...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a very hacky way of doing it that allows you to use `Object` and `instanceof` but if you can implement a proxy class that exposes a specific interface you would be better off doing that.

```
class A {

    public String getSomething() {
        return "A";
    }
}

class B {

    public String getSomethingElse() {
        return "B";
    }
}

class C implements Comparator<Object> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // Which is of what type?
        A a1 = o1 instanceof A ? (A) o1: null;
        A a2 = o2 instanceof A ? (A) o2: null;
        B b1 = o1 instanceof B ? (B) o1: null;
        B b2 = o2 instanceof B ? (B) o2: null;
        // Pull out their values.
        String s1 = a1 != null ? a1.getSomething(): b1 != null ? b1.getSomethingElse(): null;
        String s2 = a2 != null ? a2.getSomething(): b2 != null ? b2.getSomethingElse(): null;
        // Compare them.
        return s1 != null ? s1.compareTo(s2): 0;
    }

}
```

The more acceptable mechanism would be to implement a proxy class for each that implements a common interface tyhat can then be compared using a proper type-safe comparator.

```
interface P {

    public String getValue();
}

class PA implements P {

    private final A a;

    PA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return a.getSomething();
    }
}

class PB implements P {

    private final B b;

    PB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return b.getSomethingElse();
    }
}

class PC implements Comparator<P> {

    @Override
    public int compare(P o1, P o2) {
        return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: Txs. At the end I decided to take the interface way. I don't tryed the hack, but txs for the proposal.

Comment: How to invoke the compare method with the objects of PA and PB?

Answer (score 2):

If you store objects of the two unrelated types in a `Set` (which makes me wonder, since `Set`s are usually unordered), this means you are using a raw `Set`, which is not very type safe.

You can define an interface `CommonAB` that contains getter methods for all the common properties of `A` and `B`. Both `A` and `B` will implement that interface. You'll be able to put instances of `A` and `B` in a `Set<CommonAB>`.

Finally, a `Comparator<CommonAB>` will be able to compare objects of both types. The `Comparator` will access only the methods of the interface. It won't care if it's comparing two As, two Bs or an A and a B.

Comment: I saw this way, but is this the only way? Because I don't will add a Object more that I have to maintain in the time....