# Implement comparator for objects with contain list

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, arraylist, collections

i need to order complex objects. And I'm trying to implement comparator for objects with contain list: 
For example:

```
class Triangle{
   List<Point> points;
}

class Figure{
   List<Triangle> figures;
}

class FiguresComparator implements Comparator<Figure> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Figure f1, Figure f2) {
       ???
    }
}
```

Who can suggest something clear and simple?

**UPDATED:**

```
class Point {
   Integer x;
   Integer y;
}
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it. It depends on how you want the ordering to be done. Why do you need a comparator of lists of triangles?

Comment: Check out -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538866/compare-different-object-types-with-comparator

Comment: yogidilip, it's not helpful for me. but thanks!

Comment: so you will have two lists of triangles. what would make one list 'bigger' than the other? how is the Point class defined?

Comment: AbtPst, added point class

Comment: Use @romanvintonyak (and substitute username) to notify/reply to other users.