# Compare Two Different Java Objects With Different Field Names

Tags: java

I have two different objects with different field names like below.

```
class Bean1 {
   String id;
   String name;
   String lastName;

}

class Bean2 {
   String uID;
   String studentFirstName;
   String studentLastName;
}
```

I need to compare these two different java object field's values and figure out which field is different than the other.

How can I compare them?

Comment: Compare in which way? Please [edit] your question to include an example input and the result you get. Also show what you have already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, compare how? id == studentFirstName? studentFirstName == studentLastName? id.hashCode() == uID.hashCode()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare different object types with comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538866/compare-different-object-types-with-comparator)

Comment: Please compare Strings with the equals() method(s).

Answer (score 0):

if you need to know which filed didn't match, you can do it the hard way (filed vs field) or implement a equals and hasCode methods to have a general boolean result.

- filed vs field

  ```
  public boolean equals(Bean2 obj) {
      if (obj == null )return false;
      if (!id.equals(obj.uID)) return false; // print a message if u need 
      if (!name.equals(obj.studentFirstName)) return false;
      if (!lastName.equals(obj.studentLastName)) return false;
      return true;
  }
  ```